# Difficulty Rendering Geospatial Anchors Beyond some Range in ARCore. Anchor is not rendering on screen

Tags: android, geospatial, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm working on an ARCore project where I aim to create an anchor at a random latitude, longitude, and altitude. The user opens the camera from a rooftop, and when directed towards the anchor, it should be visible. The anchor can be up to 1 mile away from the current location.

I've decided to use WGS84 anchors from the ARCore Geospatial API since there may not always be a rooftop available at the specified location. To implement this, I'm using the following function to create an anchor at a particular latitude, longitude, and altitude

```
Anchor anchor = earth.createAnchor(
xx.xxxx,
xx.xxxx,
290.86,
(float) quaternion.getQ0(),
(float) quaternion.getQ1(),
(float) quaternion.getQ2(),
(float) quaternion.getQ3());
```

The function works well for loading anchors within a range of less than 100m. However, when I try to place an anchor beyond 200m, it's not rendering on the screen.

I've referred to the [this](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/geospatial/anchors) for creating anchors and following the guidelines provided. Is there any specific limitation or setting I might be missing that prevents rendering anchors beyond a certain distance?